# Is there a VR virtual desktop app for GNU/Linux?

Tags: games, steam, multimedia

I'm planning to get a HTC VIVE for watching movies in virtual reality, but the virtual desktop for steam is only for Windows.

Is there any virtual desktop app for GNU/Linux?